# Map over multiple nested arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, array.prototype.map

I am trying to map over multiple arrays and display each array's contents on the document. These arrays are nested within objects that are nested within the main array (webArray).

I am able to display the appropriate content for Test1 and Test2 with a nested for loop. I want to map this instead. When I use .map(), both contents of the arrays are listed under Test1 and Test2. This is not the behavior I want. I understand that this is happening because I am not specifying an index within webArray.map. I am unsure how to do this and have tried many things now.

```
class Website {
    constructor(name, clientSide = []) {
        this.name = name;
        this.clientSide = clientSide;
    }
}

let test1 = new Website(
    //clientSide property
    ["Pug", "SCSS", "Javascript + Jquery + Ajax"]
);

let test2 = new Website( 
     //clientSide property
     ["HTML", "SCSS", "Javascript"]
);

const webArray = [
    test1,
    test2
];

function show() {
    const output = document.getElementById("output");
    let text = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < webArray.length; i++) {
        let site = webArray[i];

        //**THIS NESTED LOOP WORKS BUT I WANT TO USE MAP INSTEAD **/
        // let listItem = [];
        // for ( let j = 0; j < site.clientSide.length; j++) {
        //     let li = site.clientSide[j];
        //     listItem.push(`<li>${li}</li>`);
        // }


        //THIS IS MY PROBLEM
        let listItems = webArray.map(function(item) {
            return `<li>${item.clientSide}</li>`; 
        });


        text.push(
            `<h1 class="test">${site.name}</h1>
                <ul>${listItems}</ul>`
        ); 

    }
    output.innerHTML = text;
}

show();
```

WHAT I WANT

**Test 1**
Pug,SCSS,Javascript + Jquery + Ajax

**Test 2**
HTML,SCSS,Javascript

WHAT I AM GETTING

**Test 1**
Pug,SCSS,Javascript + Jquery + Ajax
HTML,SCSS,Javascript

**Test 2** 
Pug,SCSS,Javascript + Jquery + Ajax 
HTML,SCSS,Javascript

Comment: You're mapping `webArray`, when you mean to be mapping `site`, in your for loop, you're doing this properly, however, when you do the map, you're mapping the full `webArray` array, which contains both objects, change the `webArray.map` to `site.map` to make it properly match your for loop code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try that and got an error in the console saying site.map is not a function.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that `site` isn't an array, you'll need to grab the array from the site object just like you did in the for loop, so you can do `site.clientSide.map`, this will properly grab the right array and map it.

Comment: Thank you so much it work! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood this correctly, you should try something like:

```js
class Website {
  constructor (name, clientSide = []) {
    this.name = name
    this.clientSide = clientSide
  }
}

const test1 = new Website(
  'test 1',
  ['Pug', 'SCSS', 'Javascript + Jquery + Ajax']
)

const test2 = new Website(
  'test 2',
  ['HTML', 'SCSS', 'Javascript']
)

const webArray = [
  test1,
  test2
]

function show () {
  const output = document.getElementById('output')
  const text = webArray.map(({ name, clientSide }) => `<h1 class="test">${name}</h1><ul>${clientSide.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`)}</ul>`)
  output.innerHTML = text
}

show()
```

```html
<div id="output">
<div>
```

You were creating 2 websites without name, but the Website constructor requires it, but the main issue was that you were creating only one `text` array and then pushing both the contents on the same array.

Hope it helps.